# Que signifie « plus que » dans cette phrase ?

Tags: grammaire, sens, expressions, prépositions, philosophie

Je serais très reconnaissant si vous pouviez m'expliquer le sens de la phrase suivante :

> Confusion absurde: plus que les notions métaphysiques importent en vérité les affirmations concrètes.

Answer (score 1):

Les composants de la phrase « Confusion absurde : [**plus que les notions métaphysiques**] [**importent en vérité**] [**les affirmations concrètes**] » ne suivent pas l'ordre traditionnel
<kbd>Sujet</kbd> → <kbd>Verbe</kbd> → <kbd>Complément</kbd> mais le plus littéraire
<kbd>Complément</kbd> → <kbd>Verbe</kbd> → <kbd>Sujet</kbd>.    ​

Remise dans un ordre habituel, la phrase devient :

> Confusion absurde : les affirmations concrètes importent en vérité plus que les notions métaphysiques.